# Closure block not reloading table on second time swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a table with button and label .When I tap on button it gets highlighted .So I have 5 rows each with button and label and when I tap on every button they are highlighted.Now on remaining view apart from table I have cancel button when I tap on it I want all the selected rows to reload again.My code works fine for the first execution .Like I selected all 5 button then tap on cancel button all rows are reloaded.But when I select button in table row again and tap on cancel nothing happens.Call is going inside my closure function I can see the correct index printed for reloading but nothing happens.My code is this-:

Cell Custom class-:

```
import UIKit

class TestingControllerCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var TableButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var TableMenu: UILabel!
    var TableButtonCallBack : (()->())?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        ButtonLayout()
        // Initialization code
    }
    func ButtonLayout()
    {
      TableButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
      TableButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
      TableButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
      self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    }

    @IBAction func filterTableRadioButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        TableButtonCallBack?()
    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

controller class-:

```
    import UIKit

    class filterControllerViewController: UIViewController {
         @IBOutlet weak var TableViewController: UITableView!
        fileprivate var ButtonSelectedIndex = [[Int]]()
        fileprivate var cancelDataItemSelectedCallBack : ((Int)->())? = nil
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            filterTableViewSetUp()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        // CANCEL ACTION
        @IBAction func cancelDataItemSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
            for sectionIndex in 0..<filterRadioButtonSelectedIndex.count
            {
                for valueIndex in 0..<ButtonSelectedIndex[sectionIndex].count
                {
                  cancelDataItemSelectedCallBack!(ButtonSelectedIndex[sectionIndex][valueIndex])
                }

            }
            ButtonSelectedIndex.removeAll()
        }



        func TableViewSetUp()
        {
            TableViewController.delegate = self
            TableViewController.dataSource = self
            TableViewController.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
        }
    }

    extension filterControllerViewController:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
    {
         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
         {
           return data.count
         }

         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
         {
            let filterCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterControllerCellTableViewCell
            filterCell.filterTableRadioButtonCallBack = {
            filterCell.TableButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            self.ButtonSelectedIndex.append([indexPath.row])
            }
    // THIS cancelDataItemSelectedCallBack CALLED FIRST TIME AND RELOAD TABLE EVEN GETS CALLED SECOND TIME SHOWS CORRECT INDEX BUT TABLE BUTTONS STLL REMAIN HIGHLIGHTED

         self.cancelDataItemSelectedCallBack = { data in
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: data, section: indexPath.section)
          print(indexPath)
                self.TableViewController.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
            }
            return filterCell
         }

         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
         {
          return 40.0
         }
}
```

I know I am missing something but not getting it.Please help

print **indexPath within self.cancelDataItemSelectedCallBac**k gives me this output which is correct.But it works only one time.

```
[0, 2]
[0, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reload the UI on the main thread like this:

```
self.cancelDataItemSelectedCallBack = { data in

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: data, section: indexPath.section)
        self.TableViewController.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }
 }
```